# Function is not defined in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a circular progress bar in react native and the error is get is rotateByStyle' is not defined.

This is a code i designed with help from an article. This must draw the circle with the progress based on certain parameters.I am using ES6 to defined the function

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';  

rotateByStyle = (percent, base_degrees, clockwise) => {
  let rotateBy = base_degrees;

  if(clockwise) {
    rotateBy = base_degrees + (percent * 3.6);
  } else {
    //anti clockwise progress
    rotateBy = base_degrees - (percent * 3.6);
  }

  return {
    transform:[{rotateZ: `${rotateBy}deg`}]
  };
}

renderThirdLayer = (percent, commonStyles, ringColorStyle, ringBgColorStyle, clockwise, bgRingWidth, progressRingWidth, innerRingStyle, startDegrees) => {
  let rotation = 45 + startDegrees;
  let offsetLayerRotation = -135 + startDegrees;

  if(!clockwise) {
    rotation += 180;
    offsetLayerRotation += 180;
  }

  if(percent > 50) {
    return <View style=    {[styles.secondProgressLayer,this.rotateByStyle((percent - 50), rotation, clockwise),
    commonStyles, ringColorStyle, {borderWidth: progressRingWidth}    ]}></View>
  } else {
    return <View 
             style={[styles.offsetLayer, innerRingStyle, ringBgColorStyle, {transform:[{rotateZ: `${offsetLayerRotation}deg`}], borderWidth: bgRingWidth}]}>
           </View>
    }
}

const CircularProgress = ({percent, radius, bgRingWidth, progressRingWidth, ringColor, ringBgColor, textFontSize, textFontWeight, clockwise, bgColor, startDegrees}) => {
  const commonStyles = {
    width: radius * 2,
    height: radius * 2,
    borderRadius: radius
  };
}

let firstProgressLayerStyle;
let displayThickOffsetLayer = false;

if(percent > 50){
  firstProgressLayerStyle = this.rotateByStyle(50, rotation, clockwise);
} else {
  firstProgressLayerStyle = this.rotateByStyle(percent, rotation, clockwise);
  if( progressRingWidth > bgRingWidth ) {
    displayThickOffsetLayer = true;
  }
}

let offsetLayerRotation = -135 + startDegrees;
if(!clockwise) {
  offsetLayerRotation += 180;
}


export default CircularProgress;
```

I expect a circular circle with progress bar

Comment: In this case, "this" mean CircularProgress, rotateByStye is out of this.
Remove "this"! just rotateByStyle is OK.
I recommend to use const  to declare function at anytime.
e.g const rotateByStyle =

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

```
this.rotateByStyle
```

=>

```
rotateByStyle
```

## Why

`rotateByStyle` is not included in `this`.

> In a method, this refers to the owner object.
>       Alone, this refers to the global object.
>       In a function, this refers to the global object.
>       In a function, in strict mode, this is undefined.
>       In an event, this refers to the element that received the event.
>       Methods like call(), and apply() can refer this to any object.

Official: [JS This](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp)

Answer (score 0):

#### You're getting this error because you need to initialize your variables using either of `const, let or var` keyword.

So in your case `rotateByStyle = ...` and `renderThirdLayer = ...` **variables** should be **declared** using any of the above mentioned keywords eg: - `const rotateByStyle = ...` for them to be **defined** and work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried const and it didn't work so  i used let

```
let rotateByStyle = (percent, base_degrees, clockwise) => {
  let rotateBy = base_degrees;

  if(clockwise) {
    rotateBy = base_degrees + (percent * 3.6);
  } else {
    //anti clockwise progress
    rotateBy = base_degrees - (percent * 3.6);
  }

  return {
    transform:[{rotateZ: `${rotateBy}deg`}]
  };
}

let renderThirdLayer = (percent, commonStyles, ringColorStyle, ringBgColorStyle, clockwise, bgRingWidth, progressRingWidth, innerRingStyle, startDegrees) => {
  let rotation = 45 + startDegrees;
  let offsetLayerRotation = -135 + startDegrees;

  if(!clockwise) {
    rotation += 180;
    offsetLayerRotation += 180;
  }

  if(percent > 50) {
    return <View style=    {[styles.secondProgressLayer,this.rotateByStyle((percent - 50), rotation, clockwise),
    commonStyles, ringColorStyle, {borderWidth: progressRingWidth}    ]}></View>
  } else {
    return <View 
             style={[styles.offsetLayer, innerRingStyle, ringBgColorStyle, {transform:[{rotateZ: `${offsetLayerRotation}deg`}], borderWidth: bgRingWidth}]}>
           </View>
    }
}
```